# document.ready function is looping because of javascript creating DOM elements

Tags: javascript, loops, bxslider, document-ready

I'm currently working on something in javascript but i'm having the following issue. I got this function:

```
$kj(document).ready(function(){
    $kj('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        minSlides: 3,
        maxSlides: 4,
        slideWidth: 170,
        slideMargin: 10,
    });
});
```

So if my document is loaded he is calling the bxSlider which has it's own javascript file. But in this javascript file there is the following function getting called:

```
setup();
```

What this does is the following (not copying all the code only the relevant piece):

```
var setup = function(){
        // wrap el in a wrapper
        el.wrap('<div class="bx-wrapper"><div class="bx-viewport"></div></div>');
        // store a namspace reference to .bx-viewport
        slider.viewport = el.parent();
        // add a loading div to display while images are loading
        slider.loader = $('<div class="bx-loading" />');
        slider.viewport.prepend(slider.loader);
        // set el to a massive width, to hold any needed slides
        // also strip any margin and padding from el
[...... more code]
});
```

As you can see this piece of code is creating DOM elements. So if i refresh or enter the page he keeps creating the bx-wrapper and bx-viewport and it's getting stuck in a never ending loop. It is probably because of the document.ready function. This function still thinks the page isn't loaded yet because my other javascript is creating DOM elements. If I do a hard refresh on the page I don't get this problem. So kinda weird tho. Anyone that has an solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Greets,

Wouter

Comment: Where do you have your `<script>` elements?

Comment: If your `<script>`s are in the `<body>` or are inside the DOM which is being modified, then they will re-execute each time. Move them into `<head>` or after `</body>`.

Comment: They are placed in the head. So that isn't the problem.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to reproduce this issue?

Comment: jQuery `ready()` is not influenced at all by dynamic objects that your code may or may not create.  It ONLY waits for the HTML in the actual page to be parsed. There should be no interaction at all between the two.

Comment: Hmm than its weird that it is still looping. Ehmm the code is quiet complex and this is the result of hours of messing with it. And can't create a jsfiddle since it is too complex and i don't know where it is going wrong. It might have something to do with the noconflict perhaps.